# starting android development

Tags: c#, android, eclipse, sdk, ide

Morning,
I am mainly a C# programmer and i am very good with C# progamming and I`d like to start developing android application.

So there are two ways for me :

- the Java way
- the C# way [preferred]

I am very newbie and i dont know what tools i should have to develop with java.
I`d like to know what version of eclipse should i use and what are the external tool id need to develop without any issue.

I`d also prefer if i developed using C# but i only installed Mono Develop and it required a license and it is complicated , so if there is any free IDE please suggest it.

I don`t have any mind learning Java as it is pretty similar to C# and also an OOP Language.

Thanks in advance

EDIT :
there is an eclipse version called : Eclipse for Mobile Developers , is that what i need ?

Comment: For the java method, android provides a tool that works specifically with eclipse that you can get from the android developer's website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Start here. It's really easy to understand.

Download the latest version of eclipse for java (if I were you I'd learn java, it's not hard and it will be easier for your development in the long run).

Download this: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42/junor

You are fine with just the standard eclipse - it is what I use.

Comment: +1 Apt answer. To improve it, you can provide a few more links to websites that provide android tutorials like [this](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html).

Comment: Thanks, they were just the sites I could think of off the top of my head. They look like useful sites I should make a note of though!!

Comment: You should now look at the "bundled" Android Development Tool (implemented with Eclipse) that brings everything you need to your development machine in a single, pre-integrated bundle!  Java is still the preferred language for Android development. See this reference: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html